# service collectd not starting properly

Tags: software-installation

after starting service collectd (to monitor system stats), I am getting below exceptios -
logfile plugin: fopen (/var/log/collectd.log) failed: Permission denied
any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it says "Permission denied" it seems that you are trying to start collectd with a user who have no write permission on /var/log/collectd.log.